# How to add a playlist onto ipod using clementine?

Tags: mp3, clementine

Hi I was wondering how you are suppose to add playlists created on my computer to my iPod using clementine?

Comment: You drag and drop the songs on the Ipod when you mount it on Nautilus

Answer (score 2):

Once you create a playlist, select all the songs in the playlist, and right-click to select "Copy Device".   I have no idea why it's so hidden.

This guy clued me in -- at 6:14 he starts talking about Devices:

[gotbletu -- Clementine - Modern Music Player - Kubuntu 10.10](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBbCUlRwPvg)